# Make To and From date range picker using jQuery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, memory-optimization, jquery-ui

I implemented date range picker logic using the jQUery UI `datepicker` component:

```
var onDocumentReady = function () {
        var datepickerConfiguration = {
            dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"
        };

        var startDatepickerHandler = function () {
            var selectedDate = $(this).val();
            var newConfiguration = Object.create(datepickerConfiguration);
            newConfiguration.minDate = moment(selectedDate, "DD/MM/YYYY").toDate();
            $("#End").datepicker('destroy');
            $("#End").datepicker(newConfiguration);
        };

        var endDatepickerHandler = function () {
            var selectedDate = $(this).val();
            var newConfiguration = Object.create(datepickerConfiguration);
            newConfiguration.maxDate = moment(selectedDate, "DD/MM/YYYY").toDate();
            $("#Start").datepicker('destroy');
            $("#Start").datepicker(newConfiguration);
        };

        ///--- Component Binding ---///
        $('#Start').datepicker(datepickerConfiguration);
        $('#End').datepicker(datepickerConfiguration);

        $('#Start').on('change', startDatepickerHandler);
        $('#End').on('change', endDatepickerHandler);

    };
    $(document).ready(onDocumentReady);
```

But I am not satisfied with this approach of setting the min and max values of `datepicker`, because in this case, it always destroys and creates a new `datepicker` on every date change. It also creates an object for configuration which may cause lot of memory waste. Please tell what would be a better approach of setting the min and max values of `datepicker`.

Comment: This sounds more like a question for Stack Overflow. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13721161/set-max-min-dates-on-jquery-ui-datepicker-on-the-fly or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16267903/jquery-datepicker-changing-mindate-and-maxdate-on-the-fly

Comment: Agree with comment from @GuyIncognito that this looks more well-suited for SO since poster is truly looking for alternate implementation advice for a known limitation of the code rather than more of an open-ended code review. More likely to get a larger set of eyes on the problem over there as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of destroying and recreating the datepickers, use the [(3<sup>rd</sup>) option method](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-option) (e.g. `.option('maxDate', selectedDate)`) to set the *minDate*/*maxDate* options when appropriate.

Also, by utilizing the [onSelect](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect) option, which receives as arguments the selected date and the datepicker instance, instead of using an onChange handler, MomentJS can be eliminated.

Lastly, the two id selectors can be combined in the same [jQuery call](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery1):

```
$('#Start, #End').datepicker(datepickerConfiguration);
```

See the simplified code below.

Another option might be to consider a daterange picker UI widget like [this one](http://tamble.github.io/jquery-ui-daterangepicker/) but perhaps the current UI is desired.

```js
//use this one handler for both Start and End Date pickers
var onDateSelect = function(selectedDate, input) {
  if (input.id === 'Start') { //Start date selected - update End Date picker
    $("#End").datepicker('option', 'minDate', selectedDate);
  } else { //End date selected - update Start Date picker
    $("#Start").datepicker('option', 'maxDate', selectedDate);
  }
};
var onDocumentReady = function() {
  var datepickerConfiguration = {
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
    onSelect: onDateSelect
  };
  ///--- Component Binding ---///
  $('#Start, #End').datepicker(datepickerConfiguration);
};
$(onDocumentReady);  // jQuery DOM ready callback registration
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<p>Start Date: <input type="text" id="Start"></p>
<p>End Date: <input type="text" id="End"></p>
```